# UnmarshalException when getting informations from my server using SOAP

Tags: spring-mvc, soap, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I try to create two simple projects, a server and a client, allowing me to manipulate SOAP technologies. I'm using Spring and CXF. I managed to create the server without problem. I have two entities: "Actor" and "Movie" which are for now independent from each other. I can add, read, edit and delete instances of these entities using SOAP UI.
I want now to create the client side. For this, I joined the wsdl files generated by CXF from my Java classes into my client project. Then Java classes are generated using the "cxf-codegen-plugin" plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/movie/movie.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <serviceName>MovieWebService</serviceName>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/actor/actor.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <serviceName>ActorWebService</serviceName>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I use only one of the wsdl file corresponding to the “Actor” service or “Movie” service everything works fine. But when I use both wsdl, I get an error like:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: élément inattendu (URI : "", local : "title"). Les éléments attendus sont <{}firstName>,<{}lastName>,<{}id>,<{}birthDate> 
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:882)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:703)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:160)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:108)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1638)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1527)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:638)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:326)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:279)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:138)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.findAll(Unknown Source)
at fr.rbillard.soap_client.controller.MovieController.getMovies(MovieController.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
- with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 168; élément inattendu (URI : "", local : "title"). Les éléments attendus sont <{}firstName>,<{}lastName>,<{}id>,<{}birthDate>]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:417)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:843)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:102)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:871)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:869)
... 59 more
Caused by: com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 168; élément inattendu (URI : "", local : "title"). Les éléments attendus sont <{}firstName>,<{}lastName>,<{}id>,<{}birthDate>
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:693)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:257)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Loader.java:124)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.childElement(Loader.java:105)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.childElement(StructureLoader.java:262)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:525)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:507)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:246)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
... 65 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: élément inattendu (URI : "", local : "title"). Les éléments attendus sont <{}firstName>,<{}lastName>,<{}id>,<{}birthDate>
... 76 more
```

Here, I tried to get the list of "Movie" from my client. The error says "title" is an unexpected element while it’s an attribute of my entity "Movie". And what is surprising is that the elements expected "firstName", "lastName", "id" and "birthDate" are the attributes of my entity "Actor".

Do you have any idea what's wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by gathering all my services in the same interface in the server side. I had :

```
@WebService(name = "ActorWebService", serviceName = "ActorWebService")
public interface ActorWebService {

    ActorDTO create(
        @WebParam(name = "firstName") String firstName, 
        @WebParam(name = "lastName") String lastName,
        @WebParam(name = "birthDate") Date birthDate);

    ...

}  

@WebService(name = "MovieWebService", serviceName = "MovieWebService")
public interface MovieWebService {

    MovieDTO creat(@WebParam(name = "title") String title);

    ...

}
```

And now I have :

```
@WebService(name = "CinemaWebService", serviceName = "CinemaWebService")
public interface CinemaWebService {

    ActorDTO createActor(
        @WebParam(name = "firstName") String firstName, 
        @WebParam(name = "lastName") String lastName,
        @WebParam(name = "birthDate") Date birthDate);

    MovieDTO createMovie(@WebParam(name = "title") String title);

    ...
}
```